# Get active directory user username from html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I have the following scenario: 
I have a single html page without login that contains form with 2 input field located on server1. 
this html page sends POST request after the user clicks on the a button to a web api which is located on sevrer2. 
The user is an active directory user.
I need to send the web api the username of the user without him entering it.
Is there any way that I can extract the username with javascript?

I've read some threads which tells that there is no way to get this username from the client side. Maybe I missed something or it can be done from the web api itself?

Thanks!

html code:

```
<form>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" ><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="lastname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
    //get details
    $('#button').click(function() {
        var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
        var lastname =  $('#lastname').val();

        var obj = { "firstname":firstname, "lastname":lastname};

        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

          $.ajax({
                url: 'server',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: myJSON,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log( data );
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log( error );
                }
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `url: 'server'`. You have to specify the whole path

Comment: You should have the user info in either the form, cookie, localstorage or a session. If i get your question correctly you do not want the user to enter their info but just click on the submit button and have access via the api.

Comment: 1. The url:'server' is censored url path.
2. Correct. I dont want the user to enter their username but to get it somehow. the question is how

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solved the problem. by defining the iis on the server to enable windows authentication and disabled annonymous I succeded to get the username which sent the request.